# After installing astyle , command astyle does not work

Tags: astyle

```
$cd astyle/build/mac
$make
$bin/astyle
```

I cannot set native locale, reverting to English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`astyle` is testing the value of the `LC_ALL` environment variable. You can see its value with `$ echo $LC_ALL`: it most likely is empty.

A quick workaround is to do `$ export LC_ALL="fr_FR.UTF-8"` but Mac OS X can be a strange beast when it comes to environment variables. I'd suggest you read these three ressources:

http://www.dowdandassociates.com/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-mac-os-x/

[Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

https://superuser.com/questions/476752/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x-for-gui-applications