# Astyle does not work in Windows

Tags: windows, astyle

I just download Astyle from SourceForge. When I execute Astyle.exe in /bin, it said 
Cannot convert to multi-byte string, reverting to English.

I don't know what happened.

I find there is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984056/after-installing-astyle-command-astyle-does-not-work), but that is about Astyle in OS X.

Here are the source code related to the error. I don't know the meaning of the second line.

```
// Not all compilers support the C++ function locale::global(locale(""));
// For testing on Windows change the "Region and Language" settings or use AppLocale.
// For testing on Linux change the LANG environment variable: LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8.
// setlocale() will use the LANG environment variable on Linux.

char* localeName = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
if (localeName == NULL)     // use the english (ascii) defaults
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\n%s\n\n", "Cannot set native locale, reverting to English");
    setTranslationClass();
    return;
}
```

Finally, please feel free to correct my English.

Answer (score 0):

Add following include to both **ASLocalizer.cpp** and **style_main.cpp**:

<#include "locale.h">